# Require identifiers not provided by a module in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

Let's say I have some file `a.rkt`:

```
#lang racket
(define a 12)
```

I now want to write some test cases, using the file `b.rkt` that requires `a.rkt`:

```
#lang racket
(require "a.rkt")
a
```

Is there any way I can get `b.rkt` to recognize the identifier defined in `a.rkt` without having to `provide` it from the first file? (Ideally without having to change the first file at all.)

I don't see anything immediately in [the documentation for require/provide](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html?q=require#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._require%29%29).

Comment: Neat idea for a self-answered question, but you might want to add more motivation in the question. I.e., clarify that this is for testing, not something you would want to do in general.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll change that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Leif mentions, RackUnit's `require/expose` *will* allow using unprovided identifiers in other modules, but [its own documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/api.html?q=require%2Fexpose#%28form._%28%28lib._rackunit%2Fmain..rkt%29._require%2Fexpose%29%29) doesn't promise a very strong guarantee:

> Note that `require/expose` can be a bit fragile, especially when mixed with compiled code. Use at your own risk!

Another approach would be to use [submodules](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Module_Syntax.html?q=submodule#%28part._submodules%29), which can effectively provide a sanctioned way to export a private API for use in tests or other means.

For example, consider a module that implements a function to test if a string contains a single word:

```
#lang racket

(provide word?)

(define (word? str)
  (not (ormap space? (string->list str))))

(define (space? c)
  (eq? c #\space))
```

(This is, perhaps, not the most realistic example, but bear with me.)

It might be useful to test the `space?` function to ensure it works, but it likely shouldn't be part of the public API. To create an "escape hatch", it's possible to define a submodule that exports this binding:

```
(module+ for-testing
  (provide space?))
```

The name `for-testing` is arbitrary—it could be anything. Either way, it is now possible to require that submodule in another module to get access to the private bindings:

```
#lang racket

(require rackunit
         (submod "a.rkt" for-testing))

(check-true (space? #\space))
(check-false (space? #\a))
```

This is something of a safer way to expose identifiers from modules without exposing them to all consumers.

Comment: Sometimes, it's unfeasible to change the original source to add extra `provide`s, e.g., students who do not follow directions. Dan Feltey's testing framework uses `require/expose` (and friends) in this manner: https://github.com/dfeltey/pdptest. (Not contradicting your answer, just describing another use case context.)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`require/expose`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/api.html?q=require%2Fexpose#%28form._%28%28lib._rackunit%2Fmain..rkt%29._require%2Fexpose%29%29) in `b.rkt` to get access to the binding in `a.rkt`. `b.rkt` would look something like this:

```
#lang racket
(require rackunit)
(require/expose "a.rkt" (a))
a
```